# How to get Image from Rss

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser

Thanks for your previous replies,

I am trying to parse an image from Rss feed, but the tag name for the image url differs from many RSS feeds. I have given the url, _imageE in SAX parser, but the URL will not fetch from the RSS xml. In some RSS they provide an image link like `<media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="http://imageLink/image.jpg"/>` how can I parse this kind of image url. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding what that element means.  According to [the specification](http://video.search.yahoo.com/mrss), the `url` attribute is mandatory and contains the URL of the thumbnail image.  So you can simply extract it using the SAX parser.  Once you've extracted the URL, you should be able to use HTTP to fetch the image that the URL refers to.  There's not much point "parsing" the URL.

Comment: Can you point to an example of SAX parser with media support? Thanks.

Comment: @happyhardik - your question doesn't make any sense.  The image isn't in the `<media:thumbnail>` element.  The element contains a *link* to the image that you have to *fetch* from somewhere else.  Parsers don't do that.

Comment: Yes, I found the problem, I had a look at my RSSHandler file and got it. thanks for your help! :)